# Replace old object on bucket Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a new bucket and 1 object inside. Object was uploaded from Revit file. When i change something on revit file and try to upload it again with the same name I always have the same old model on Forge as the first times, not thing was updated.
I use Nodejs and configure for the upload look like this.

```
 let opts = {'xAdsForce': true}
 try {
      await new DerivativesApi().translate(job, opts, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
```

Is there something wrong ?. Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Passing in the `xAdsForce: true` option is the right way to force the translation even if the object with the same name has already been translated. According to the [docs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate) this method should return a promise that resolves in a `Job` object. Try investigating this value to see if everything is ok. Also make sure that the upload of your updated Revit file actually succeeded.

Alternatively, you can try triggering the translation manually, by making a request to the [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST) endpoint, with `x-ads-force` header in the request set to `true`.

Comment: Thank Petr for your answer, after spending time searching for it i figure out the answer   is just simply clean browser catch after upload the new object.